# How to extract the most frequent value of the field from List[Map[String,String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have these data:

```
val data = List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187513, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc), 
     Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 111),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187522, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc))
```

I want to extract the most frequent `event_name`. In this case it should be `visited`. However, it must be considered that not all entries of the `List` have the field `event_name`. How can I do it?

If I would need to just extract any `event_name`, then this works. But it does not give me the most frequent one:

```
val event_name = data.collect{
    case map if map.keySet.contains("event_name") => map("event_name")
}.headOption.getOrElse("")
```

Also I wrote this code, but it does not assume that some of the entries might not have `event_name`:

```
val event_name = data.map(l=>l("event_name")).groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
```

Comment: try `data.flatMap(_.get("event_name"))`

Comment: @Łukasz: Do you mean this? `data.flatMap(_.get("event_name")).groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. You were close to the solution :)